# Is there any data recorded for consumption of Azure DevOps Services Dashboards?

Tags: azure-devops

My client wants to know last accessed date for each dashboard. Does ADO have any way to record such data? I imagine it could be done using a custom widget (extension) and placing that on each dashboard, but is there some easier way?

Comment: which dashboards are you referring here?

Comment: Azure DevOps Services (ADO) Team dashboards.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is no, there is not.
Source: Microsoft Support